# Why does this method of Java Scanner works in code 2 and not code 1?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

What is the reason?Why does the code 2 works and  code 1 is showing error?
I  first used the code 1 approach..it displayed error and then I tried adding it in a method..it worked somehow..please let me know the reason

Code 1:

```
import java.util.*;
class alpha /*This is not the main class btw */
{
   Scanner x=new Scanner(System.in);
   int k;flag=0;
   String s1=new String();
   s1=x.nextLine(); /* This Line Produces error */
}
```

Code 2:

```
import java.util.*;
class alpha /*This is not the main class btw */
{
   Scanner x=new Scanner(System.in);
   int k;flag=0;
   String s1=new String();
   void input()
   {
     s1=x.nextLine(); /* Voila this works */
   }
}
```

Comment: The first example doesn't declare any methods -- and outside of a method, you can only have field declarations (like `int k` or `String s1 = "foo"`), not statements (like `s1=whatever`). Your second example puts that `s1=` statement within a method. This is all very fundamental Java, so if you haven't yet, I would _strongly_ suggest reading through a Java tutorial or book. If you try to pick up the basics "on the fly" rather than in a systemic way, you're likely to miss a lot of important things -- like what a statement is, and where you can and can't write one.

Comment: Only declarations and initializers are allowed at class level, the like producing the error is an assignment statement. Code should go into methods

Answer (score 1):

Your first example doesn't run because we can't put statements  outside any method,we  can only put declarations and initializers outside a method like

`int x = 5;`

`Hello h = new Hello;`

that is the reason your first example is showing error

You should not put statements like `s1=x.nextLine();` outside any method.